# Insert records sql

Tags: sql, select, insert

There are multiple records

For example:

```
   ID Name subject   cindex
    1   abc   mat      45
    2   jjj   scie     45
    3   kkk   geom     45  
    4   sdf   eng      45
    5   idf   law      45
```

Now I want to insert the same records but with different `cindex`. I tried this:

```
insert into b_table (ID,name,subject,cindex) values (+1,NULL,NULL,90)
select name,subject from b_table where cindex=45
```

Here `ID` is not an autoincrement column. I tried to do with +1 .. now I think this query is not correct, so how do I select records and insert the same records with different `cindex`?

Comment: If you already have 1, 2, 3 and then add 1, the insert will try to insert 2, 3, 4. I.e. duplicate id values!

Comment: tell us the error you are getting

Comment: no want to insert with different cindex and obviously different ID ..

Comment: In mysql you can make the field A_I, in ORACLE you have to define a trigger on Table insert.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a sub-query that returns the table's max id. Add that value to each selected id.

```
insert into b_table (ID,name,subject,cindex)
  select id + (select max(id) from b_table), Name, subject, 90
  from b_table where cindex = 45
```

Comment: complicated :/ .. i did not understand why u select  90 as cindex from table because there is no record with cindex 90 in table ?

Comment: Don't you want to insert cindex 90 instead of 45?

Comment: Here you INSERT what the SELECT returns. If you SELECT 90, that value will be inserted!

Comment: but still not understand why we select 90 in select statement .. why not in insert statement. we insert 90 not select

Comment: please clarify this ..  @jarih

Comment: @superuser No need for another clarification, I already clarified this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't insert anything to `ID` column if it's autoincrement , use this:

```
insert into b_table (id,name,subject,cindex)
select (SELECT max(id) FROM b_table) + id,name,subject,90 from b_table where cindex=45
```

**EDIT:** For clarification of the question you asked in the comments, take this table for example :

```
ID, NAME
1    super
2    sagi
3    josh

SELECT id, name , 'bla bla bla' as constant_string, 45 constant_number
FROM Table
```

Will output the following:

```
ID,name,constant_string,constant_number
1  super    'bla bla bla'   45
2  sagi     'bla bla bla'   45
3  josh     'bla bla bla'   45
```

When you select a string, or a number, they are not selected from the actual table data. They are being generated as a constant value "attached" to your data .

Comment: "ID is not autoincrement".

Comment: For some reason I've read it as "ID is autoincrement" :) @jarlh

Comment: but there is no 90 cindex in table so how i select 90 ?

Comment: yes id is not  autoincrement want to do that with +1 .. like id +1 ??

Comment: When you select a number / string -> `'CONSTANT_VALUE' it will be selected as a constant value, and not a value from the table @superuser

Comment: How can people with such high reputation help someone in simple queries. Is it not against ethos of stackoverflow! @sagi

Comment: high reputation does not mean u can not help someone @ubaidashraf

Comment: @ubaidashraf It's not that simple question, and SQL beginners doesn't usually know how to have a sub select for the max id .

Comment: @sagi Don't you think this query can be resolved by little effort of googling. That is what I am trying to say. Being unable to find solution easily in first place is what should bring users here

Comment: @superuser Stackoverflow is the community where basic motive is to help fellow members. What I meant is they could have guided you in correct direction rather than providing you complete solution. That would have helped you better.

Comment: I can easily find any solution to any question you have regarding SQL online, that's because I know what to look for. Beginners usually use the wrong search words so they won't find what they are looking for.. @ubaidashraf

Comment: @sagi Agree with you completely. But maybe you could have guided him towards answer rather than providing complete solution. :)

Comment: working thanku............@ubaidashraf i also search on google but cant find suitable solution

Comment: You could have searched for "sql simulate auto increment" , which I believe would have produce more than enough results on the subject .

Comment: @ubaidashraf Yes you are right as well. I guess it depends on the day I open the question :)